# Is the following function strongly convex?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis

I've tried to check the Hessian and  see whether the following function is strongly convex w.r.t the euclidian norm however this function is not diff. at the origin.

$g(x)=||x||_2+||x||_2^2$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strong convexity does not require differentiability.

A function is strongly convex if *and only if* it can be written in the form $g(x)=f(x)+\mu\|x\|_2^2$ where $f(x)$ is convex and $\mu>0$ is fixed. That is the case here: $f(x)=\|x\|_2$ and $\mu=1$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions) offers several alternate definitions of strong convexity.